# Error: Incomplete RPL stream received (length = 168331)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Does anyone have a clue what this SSRS error means?  the only thingi found on google say to upgrade to sp1, but i'm already on sp1.  I have a report that generates this error when i run the report.  i tried redeploying the report to no avail.  However, all the other reports that i tested on the server work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i couldn't figure out anything other than the rld might have been corrupted, so i recreated the report and redeployed and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

We just observed this with our system.  The root cause was SQL ran server too low on memory for SSRS to complete it's report operation.